# TextPad Tortoise Merge Tool

Tags: tortoise-svn, comparison, textpad

I am trying to create a custom tool in TextPad to call the Tortoise SVN merge tool.

If I have two files open in TextPad, I want to diff them with TortoiseMerge by going to Tools -> TortoiseMerge in TextPad. I don't want to have to manually add any file paths, I want these to be picked up via TextPad.

I am having trouble with the parameters for the tool, here is what I have:

```
Command: C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseMerge.exe
Parameters: $File $File
Initial folder: $FileDir
```

This successfully diffs the same file - is there any means of getting the path to the other open file .. a similar $File variable or some other means..?

Many thanks.

Comment: Consider using the TortoiseMerge command line arguments found here: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseMerge_en/tme-automation.html#tme-automation-basics

Comment: Yeah I'm already using them, the 'Parameters' field of the TextPad tool configuration acts as the command line args. I'm trying to figure out how to get the path of the other open file, in order to do the diff. $File gives me the path to the document I have open, I need something that lets me find the path to other open documents.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted this too, but it doesn't seem to be possible in one step.

Instead, I setup two simple tools:

1. ctrl-1 
   copy $file C:\temp\temp1.txt
2. ctrl-2
   TortoiseMerge $file C:\temp\temp1.txt

So you select the first file and hit ctrl-1, then switch to the second file and hit ctrl-2.